# mongoose cannot populate using type String

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

So I have this `FacilityPersonnel` model with fields :

```
var field = {
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},

    some_id: {type: String},
    fooAccessType: {
        type: String, 
        default: 'SuperAdmin', 
        ref: 'AccessType'
    },  
}
```

Im trying to `populate` the  `fooAccessType` using this on **controller**.

```
FacilityPersonnel.findOne({_id:req.params.id})
    .populate('fooAccessType')
    .exec(function (err, doc) {
        if (err) { res.status(500).json(err); return; };
        res.status(200).json(doc);
    })
```

All data to be queried are all available and the query is working when I removed the line `.populate('fooAccessType')` but if not I returns this error :

```
{
    "stack": "Error\n    at MongooseError.CastError ...",
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"SuperAdmin\" at path \"_id\"",
    "name": "CastError",
    "kind": "ObjectId",
    "value": "SuperAdmin",
    "path": "_id"
}
```

Why is that? Thanks.

Comment: This would only work if the referenced `AccessType` model's schema defines `_id` as a string, and there's a referenced doc with an `_id` that contains that `'SuperAdmin'` value.

Comment: I knew it. Thanks @JohnnyHK

Answer (score 2):

Currently, only `ObjectId` values which refer to the `_id` of another collection can be used as `refs`.

Here is one discussion https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2562

However, it could be one enhancement in the future.

---

Actually, it is no need to add `default` value to `populate` field, just define the `fooAccessType` as below

```
fooAccessType: {
    type: String, 
    ref: 'AccessType'
},
```

For `population`

```
FacilityPersonnel.findOne({_id:req.params.id})
    .populate('fooAccessType')
    .exec(
```

---

The `ObjectID` is used in the `population`, and the `ObjectId` is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:

> a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
>
> a 3-byte machine identifier,
>
> a 2-byte process id, and
>
> a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

So `SuperAdmin` is not one correct `ObjectID`. You could use [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-uuid) as the default value of `ObjectID`

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

// ...
fooAccessType: {
    type: String, 
    default: uuid.v1, 
    ref: 'AccessType'
},
```

However, the above code is weird, the `fooAccesType` is reference to `AccessType` document.

When try to save the `field` document, the `AccessType` should be saved firstly, then get the `ObjectID` from this saved `AccessType` and assign it to `fooAccessType`, eventually,  save the new `field` document.

```
var access = new AccessType({});
access.save(function(err){
   if (err)
      // error handling
   else {
       facilityperson.fooAccessType = access._id;
       facilityperson.save(function(err) {

       });
   }
});
```

For `population`

```
FacilityPersonnel.findOne({_id:req.params.id})
    .populate('fooAccessType')
    .exec(
```

Comment: And then how do I populate that?

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx, I think it is no need to give the default value to `ref` field.  I have updated my answer, forgive me if I misunderstand your question.

Comment: Hi I will try this. But I have reason why I added a default value for the field. It is meant that the value of the `fooAccessType` should be 'SuperAdmin', or 'Creator' etc... That's why I used the String 'SuperAdmin' to be the reference id for population.

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx, based my understanding, the `ref` field is the `ObjectID` of document, rather than the `superAdmin` as you mentioned.

Comment: No. The `ref` is the `AccessType` which is a **document**, and the `ref` field is not `ObjectId` I want to use the `superAdmin` as a unique identifier to populate the contents of `AccessType` document.

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx, refer to this link https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2562, you issue could be done as one enhancement in the future.

Comment: I see. I think I will just change my logic. Thank you very much though!

Answer (score 0):

```
FacilityPersonnel.findOne({_id:req.params.id})
    .populate({ path: "fooAccessType", model: "AccessType" })
    .exec()
```