# Mongo Relationships/Referencing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB references. Right now I have one collection which I call `users`. It stores all users and their keys. I have another collection which has data for each key.

I want to just use their key as the ID to connect them. So I will have each key generated and and the keyData will be empty when first created and then I will just keep adding objects to the keyData array. That is my plan, but I do not know how I create the relation with the schema.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Create Schema 

const userKey = new Schema({
    _id : {
        type : String,
        required: true
    },
    key: {
        type : String,
        required: true
    },
    keyData: [key],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});


module.exports = Key = mongoose.model('key', userKey);
```

This doesn't work because I cannot access the key before initialization. So how canI relate the two collections?

Comment: You need two separate schemas example `userModel` and `keyModel` to separately manage `users` and `keys` collections and link it like the way it is shown here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: I am still very confused on how I would do these. How will it know which id to use ?

Comment: In which collection are u storing key details? As per your question u have one collection where u store user details.

Comment: I have two schema the one I show in my code is the one that holds all the users key.

Comment: then I have another one that holds an array of data where I plan on just appending objects of data to it.

Comment: I guess I understood your question now. U want to automatically add objects into the `keyData` array after an insertion happens into `data` collection? if so just read about mongoose post hooks: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post

Comment: Your last answer actually worked for me after a few adjustments but you took it down while I was writing thank you haha .

Comment: I have undeleted it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Schema #1: userData

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create User-data Schema 
const userData = new Schema({
  data: {
    type: Array,
    require: true
  }
},
{
  collection: 'data' // Mentioning collection name explicitly is good!
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('data', userData);
```

Schema #2: Keys

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create User-Key Schema 
const userKey = new Schema({
  key: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  keyData: { 
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'data' 
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
},
{
  collection: 'keys' // Mentioning collection name explicitly is good!
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('keys', userKey);
```

As per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363318/mongoose-cannot-populate-using-type-string) its not possible to set string as `ref`s. So in your `keys` schema use `ObjectId` as `ref`.

Comment: This confuses me even more. You made two schemas for the same thing? Users and Keys are the same . We identify our users with their keys. Then I want to have another collection which will have an array of objects where it would hold the data. Each key will have its own data. If that makes sense.

Comment: I will put what I have in a " Answer your question" since I cannot edit my current post for some reason its glitched for me.

Comment: Try it out but u are missing second point `_id` cant be of `string` type.

Comment: Yea , I just changed that in my code. I am going to test right now. Would I just initialize the userKey schema and it would automatically generate the useData schema  ?

Comment: This did not work for me. For the keydata field it just comes out as : Array/empty array

Comment: This didn't work for me either. None of them even have a keyData attribute. Where/When would I initialize the keydata ?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
const userData = new Schema({
    _id : {
        type : String,
        required: true
    },
    data : {
        type : Array,
        require: true
    }
});

const userKey = new Schema({
    _id : {
        type : String,
        required: true
    },
    key: {
        type : String,
        required: true
    },
    keyData: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'data' }],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});




module.exports = KeyData = mongoose.model('data', userData);
module.exports = Key = mongoose.model('key', userKey);
```